# How to do aggregation with sum in a Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I'm new to MongoDB and need to write this query. My JSON Request is like this. I need to build the query in mongodb with aggregation

JSON

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Test",
      "status": "Lost",
      "lead_value": 78000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Trail",
      "status": "Trial",
      "lead_value": 75200
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Teja",
      "status": "Customer",
      "lead_value": 45000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Kushbu",
      "status": "Trial",
      "lead_value": 20000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Krishna",
      "status": "Trial",
      "lead_value": 18000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "LeadName": "Test1",
      "status": "Trial",
      "lead_value": 12000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "89",
      "name": "Prashanth Reddy",
      "LeadName": "Ganesh",
      "status": "Trial",
      "lead_value": 12000
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "89",
      "name": "Prashanth Reddy",
      "LeadName": "Hima Sree",
      "status": "Customer",
      "lead_value": 1750
    }
  }
]
```

I want the response like sum of the all the "Lead_values" except "Customer" and count the Status also

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "name": "Madhu",
      "lead_value": 120354,
      "count" : 5
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user_id": "89",
      "name": "Prashanth Reddy",
      "lead_value": 12000,
      "count" : 1
    }
  }
]
```

How to write in MongoDB Aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a simple [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id.status": {$ne: "Customer"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.user_id",
            lead_values: {$sum: "$_id.lead_value"},
            name: {$first: "$_id.name"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

You can now reformat the data as you wish.

Comment: Some typos, I think you meant `"_id.status": {$ne: "Customer"}` and so on in the group stage fields. Because in OP's data the documents are actually inside `_id` property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this query working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query, to get your perfect result.
Here is it.

```
db.getCollection('YOUR_COLLECTION').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id.status": {$ne: "Customer"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.user_id",
            lead_values: {$sum: "$_id.lead_value"},
            name: {$first: "$_id.name"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

Here you can see, how we can use [$sum with $group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)